# How can i optimize the following code for better memory usage?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */

class Codechef
{

     String func (String s1)
    {
        StringTokenizer st =new StringTokenizer(s1);
        String fina= new String();
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String s= st.nextToken();
                char []ch= s.toCharArray(); 
                int length= ch.length;
                int r=0;
                int i =1;
                while(i<=length/2)
                    {  

                        char temp;
                        temp=ch[i];
                        ch[i]=ch[length-1-r];
                        ch[length-1-r]=temp;
                        r++;
                        i++;
                     }


                String revword=new String(ch);
                fina+=""+revword +" ";

            }

            return(fina);

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s1="Tarun is a intern";  
        Codechef c=new Codechef();
        String s2=c.func(s1);
        System.out.println(""+s2);
    }
}
```

The above code was run on **codechef ide** i am using **2638 KB of memory**.
Is there any other method I can use to decrease the memory usage?
Or any other optimized method?
I tried using StringBuilder to append as it is mutable still it was giving me same memory usage on code chef.

Comment: SO is not really the place for CodeReviews, there are better suited parts of this community for that. One thing, though: stop using StringTokenizer, it became deprecated several versions of Java ago. whatever flaws it had/has, you can bet on it they weren't fixed. Switch to the String.split(""); method, instead

Comment: Looks like you're creating 2*`numTokens` `String`s. Maybe start there.

Comment: StringBuilder instead of String concatenation would also help

Comment: Actually, it's more than that as you you concat to `fina` too.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @UwePlonus i didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question would probably be better on codereview.stackexchange.com but nevertheless, I'll make some comments here.

Out of the 2638 KB of memory used, I expect the vast majority of that is used by the Java Runtime Environment, rather than directly by your application. Still you might make a few KB of savings. Here's a line-by-line commentary.

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */
```

No need to keep the above line in your code.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */

class Codechef
{

     String func (String s1)
    {
        StringTokenizer st =new StringTokenizer(s1);
```

The documentation of StringTokenizer says this is a legacy class kept for backward compatibility and that newer code should use `String.split()` instead. This would improve readability, though I doubt it would improve performance or memory usage.

```
        String fina= new String();
```

Why are you using `new String()`? Just use `""`. By using `new String()` you are creating a new object, thus wasting a few bytes of memory, when `""` refers to an existing object, and is more readable.

```
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String s= st.nextToken();
                char []ch= s.toCharArray(); 
                int length= ch.length;
                int r=0;
```

It may be slightly more readable to start `r` at 1 and use `length-r` instead of `length-1-r`.

```
                int i =1;
```

You need to start `i` at 0, as this is the index of the first character.

```
                while(i<=length/2)
```

It may be more readable to use a `for` loop.

```
                    {  

                        char temp;
                        temp=ch[i];
```

Why not declare and initialize on the same line? `char temp = ch[i];`

```
                        ch[i]=ch[length-1-r];
                        ch[length-1-r]=temp;
                        r++;
                        i++;
                     }


                String revword=new String(ch);
                fina+=""+revword +" ";
```

There is no need for the `""+` preceding revword. You are creating a new String by doing this (thus wasting memory). But `revword` is already a string, so no need to append it to a null string.

Appending to a `String fina` inside a loop costs CPU time (and some memory). You should use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Also, if you used `StringBuilder` you would have been able to copy `ch` to it directly, without having to create a new `String` that is a copy of `ch`.

```
            }

            return(fina);
```

Minor nit-pick: no need for parentheses here, as it makes the `return` keyword look like a method call, which it is not.

```
    }
```

By the way, your method adds a `" "` (space) at the end of the returned string, which is probably not what you want.

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s1="Tarun is a intern";  
        Codechef c=new Codechef();
        String s2=c.func(s1);
        System.out.println(""+s2);
    }
}
```